# android, onProgressUpdate is not running

Tags: android, android-asynctask

i have a problem with below's code, onProgressUpdate is not running ... however the onPreExecute, doInBackground and onPostExecute is execute accordingly. or do i need a return in doInBackground? please advice me what is missed.
i used to deleted

```
notification.contentView.setProgressBar(R.id.pbStatus, 100, progress, false);
notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(getApplicationContext().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.notify(42, notification);
```

in onCreate, then the notification didn't appear at all. below is the full code :

```
package com.android.MaxApps;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class StaffChoice extends Activity { 
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    private int progress;

    Intent MyI;
    PendingIntent MyPI;
    NotificationManager MyNM;
    Notification notification;
NotificationManager notificationManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.staffchoices);       

    MyI = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MaxAppsAct.class);
    MyPI = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, MyI, 0);
    MyNM = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MaxAppsAct.class);
    final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);

    notification = new Notification(R.drawable.logo, "Downloading...", System.currentTimeMillis());
    notification.flags = notification.flags | Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
    notification.contentView = new RemoteViews(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), R.layout.staffchoices);
    notification.contentIntent = pendingIntent;
    notification.contentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.imgIcon, R.drawable.save);
    notification.contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.tvText, "Downloading...");
    notification.contentView.setProgressBar(R.id.pbStatus, 100, progress, false);
    notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(getApplicationContext().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(42, notification);

    String url = "http://www.domainURL.com/3d.png"; 
    new DownloadFileAsync().execute(url);
    }

public class DownloadFileAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        super.onPreExecute();
        }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... aurl) {
        int count;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(aurl[0]);
            URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
            conexion.connect();

            int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();
            Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC", "Lenght of file: " + lenghtOfFile);

            File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/MaxApps");
            boolean success = false;
            if (!folder.exists()) {
                success = folder.mkdirs();
            }
            if (!success) {
            } else {
            }

            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/MaxApps/3d.png");

            byte data[] = new byte[1024];

            long total = 0;

            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
            total += count;
            publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));
            output.write(data, 0, count);
            }

            output.flush();
            output.close();
            input.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {}

        return null;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {          
        notification.contentView.setProgressBar(R.id.pbStatus, 100, progress[0], false);
        notificationManager.notify(42, notification);
        }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String unused) {           
        notificationManager.cancel(42);

        Notification MyN = new Notification(); MyN.icon = R.drawable.logo1;
        MyN.tickerText = "Download Complete"; 
        MyN.number = 1; 
        MyN.setLatestEventInfo (getApplicationContext(), "Application Title", "Application Description", MyPI); 

        MyNM.notify(1, MyN);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Did you remove the "@Override" from the method?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You declare your `DownloadFileAsync` class to publish progress updates as Strings:

```
public class DownloadFileAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
```

Yet you define `onProgressUpdate()` to take Integers:

```
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
```

As such, it isn't the `onProgressUpdate()` that `AsyncTask` uses.  Assuming you want to use Strings, it should become

```
@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
```

My guess is that you actually want to declare your class as:

```
public class DownloadFileAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Void>
```

In which case you can leave your `onProgressUpdate()` unchanged other than adding `@Override`.  `onPostExecute()` would become

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
```

Which is clearer than `(String unused)`, since it's not used.

General advice:

1. `@Override` is your friend, as it helps catch this type of error.
2. Be sure to read the documentation for [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), as you seem a little confused about its usage.  That page explains these issues well.

Comment: thanks for the reply, i follow ur step and i get this error at publishProgress "The method publishProgress(Integer...) in the type AsyncTask<String,Integer,Void> is not applicable for the arguments (String)"

Comment: That's because you're still calling it with a String.  Change `publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));` to `publishProgress((int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));`  Also note that you might want to change `lenghtOfFile` to `lengthOfFile`.

Comment: after onProgressUpdate is done, now it wont run onPostExecute...i removed @Override from onPostExecute

Comment: @melvintcs No, leave the `@Override` in -- that's very important for making sure your declaration matches the superclass's, and in this case that you've declared your class properly.  Please post your current `public class DownloadFileAsync extends...` and `protected void onPostExecute(...` lines.

Comment: sorry, i removed the @Override before i read ur updated answer. the onPostExecute is running now. it works fine. I had update my question at thread 1, have a look. i tried on my Xperia Arc S and Samsung S2, the system will freeze until the download is complete.  possible to solve this?

Comment: @melvintcs First, I'm not sure why you're seeing a freeze-up. That sounds like a topic for a separate question. Second, regarding changing your code in your question, you should leave the code that doesn't work. The whole point is to have this Q&A here for when someone else has a similar problem. By correcting your code, you make it much harder for that to work. I strongly recommend that you roll back your edit (click the "edited X mins ago" link, scroll down to the original, and click "rollback"). You can post the current version in the new question if you think it's related to your freeze.

Comment: ok, already rolled back. thanks for helping me all this way :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are passing a string as argument `publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));` whereas `protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress)` is expecting an Integer. I suppose you are going wrong in this scenario.